# Nesting multiple IF AND statement conditionals

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to write a nested IF statement in Excel that's contingent on criteria in two different cells.

1. If T2 equals "sold" AND I2 is NOT blank OR I2 does NOT equal "guest" THEN I want to return the value in I2.
2. When the value in T2 equals "sold" but I2 is empty or equals "guest" THEN return the value in E2.

I'm not quite getting there with this:

```
=IF(AND(T2="sold",I2<>"guest"),I2,IF(AND(I2="guest",ISBLANK(I2)),I2,E2))
```

Comment: Return the value form which cell?

Answer (score 2):

There is no contingency for T2 not equalling "Sold" so I've added a value you can easily locate and modify. Perhaps it should just be an empty string.

```
=IF(T2="sold", IF(AND(I2<>"",I2<>"guest"),I2, E2), "T2 is not sold")
```

Comment: So helpful! Thank you so much!